# React: How to setState based on data from child component?

Tags: reactjs

My page has a child component with an `input`.  I am trying to use the value of this input box to `setState` of the parent, i.e. the user types in a name and hits enter, and when they do so, the value of that `input` is sent to the parent page and used to `setState {( familyName: [insert string here] )}`.

In the child component (called Breadcrumbs):

```
<input type="text" id="familyNameText" />
<input type="button" onClick={this.props.setStateHandler} value="OK" />
```

In the parent:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({ familyName: 'Oldfamily' });
    this.updateFamilyName = this.updateFamilyName.bind(this);
  }
  updateFamilyName(data) {
    this.setState({ familyName: data });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <main>
        <UserMenu />
        <Header />
        <Breadcrumbs setStateHandler={this.updateFamilyName} /> {/* breadcrumbs.js will access this via 'this.props.setStateHandler' */}
        <Sidebar />
        <Layout>
          <h2>The {this.state.familyName} Family</h2>
```

However when I click OK, the state remains unchanged and the console says:

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances, nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, pageX, pageY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, getModifierState, button, buttons, relatedTarget, movementX, movementY, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped}).
    in h2 (at familyinfo.js:27)`

What does this error mean?  Why isn't my `setState` code setting the state, and what's wrong with trying to access information from the page's state in my `<h2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument coming back from the child (`data`) is the [event handler object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).
So you can get the `target.value` from this object:

```
updateFamilyName(data) {
    this.setState({ familyName: data.target.value });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you pass the handler directly to the event handler, it will be called with the event object and hence you need to get the value and set it in state

```
  updateFamilyName(e) {
    this.setState({ familyName: e.target.value });
  }
```

Since you want the value of the input, you should probably add it in the child state onChange and pass it back to parent onSubmit

```
<input type="text" id="familyNameText" onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} value={this.state.value}/>
<input type="button" onClick={() => this.props.setStateHandler(this.state.value)} value="OK" />
```

and use it like

```
  updateFamilyName(data) {
    this.setState({ familyName: data });
  }
```

Comment: Haha, this returned "The OK Family" (the value of the button clicked, not the input before it).  Should I wrap the input and button in a form and use `onSubmit` or something?

Comment: ohh, you want the input value, its better to set the input value in state of the child onChange and then pass it back on to the parent on submit

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the data object which you get in the updateFamilyName function is not a string but an object.

You need you explore this object to see which property you are looking for,you can try:

```
data.target.value
```

Start with printing the object to the console to see what are you getting.